# Android popup menu from home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget, popupmenu

I want to show a popup menu from a home screen widget like the one in the picture below, but there is a `View anchor` argument in the PopupMenu constructor method.

But I don't have access to the view in `AppWidgetProvider` class and only the RemoteViews are available.

So, How can I implement a popup menu in my widget?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Popup menu from widget]

Comment: Is this screenshot an actual widget or a design mock?

Comment: @Karakuri This is a actual working widget on my phone!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu` directly with `RemoteViews`. But you are able to copy that behaviour:

1. Add an anchor view to your RemoteViews layout (this view can be any supported view: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout)
2. Create a `PendingIntent` with a defined intent action and set it with `setOnClickPendingIntent` for the anchor view
3. Catch that `Intent` in `onReceive` of your `AppWidgetProvider`by the intent action
4. Call `intent.getSourceBounds()` to get the screen position of the clicked anchor view
5. Start a full transparent `Activity` and transmit the screen position to that `Activity`
6. Create and open a `PopupMenu` at the transmitted screen position in the transparent `Activity`
7. `finish()` the transparent `Activity` if the user clicks not on an item of the `PopupMenu`